# Issue in connecting Python with MySQL on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: python, mysql, google-cloud-platform

I have used the following code in Python:

```
import mysql.connector as mysql
import sys


HOST = "34.87.95.90" 
DATABASE = "CAO_db"
USER = "root"
PASSWORD = "*********" 


db_connection = mysql.connect(user=USER, password=PASSWORD, host=HOST, database=DATABASE)
cur = db_connection.cursor()
```

When I run the above code, I get the following error messages:

TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '34.87.95.90:3306' (10060 A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond)

I am not sure of how to fix my code and/or resolve the given errors. Please ask me if you would like more details of the error messages to help with the issue. I would greatly appreciate all the help I can get towards resolving the issues.

Comment: Where is deployed your MySQL database? On a compute engine? on Cloud SQL?

Comment: Also add which version of MySQL.

Comment: The MySQL database is on Google Cloud Platform. MySQL 8.0 is the version.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I'm not seeing here is whether or not you have configured your Cloud SQL instance to accept connections.

You can configure it to accept connections from within the GCP stratosphere using their "Private IP" internal networking magic, AND you can configure it to accept connections from other machines using a combination of Public IP and either an authorized external network (like if you were accessing your GCP Cloud SQL instance from, say, an Amazon EC2 instance), or their Cloud SQL Proxy tool (which is what I use to connect to my Cloud SQL instance from my laptop).

1. In the GCP Console, go to your project
2. From the hamburger menu, select SQL
3. Click on your Cloud SQL instance
4. In the left nav, click on *Connections*
5. If you have Private IP checked and you're running this code on a GCP Compute/GKE resource, confirm that the "Network" field is set to the network used by that resource.
6. If you're just trying to get a connection from your local machine and you don't have a static IP to whitelist, your best option is to use Public IP in combination with [Cloud SQL Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/quickstart-proxy-test).

Cloud SQL Proxy essentially creates a TCP tunnel that allows your laptop to connect to 'localhost' on a port you specify, and it then redirects your connection to the remote Cloud SQL instance.

Once you've established that your networking situation isn't the problem, you could use the same Python connection code that you wrote above, but change HOST to 127.0.0.1 and add an attribute for PORT=3308.

---

EDITED to add: I suggest using PORT=3308 for your cloud_sql_proxy connection so that it doesn't interfere with any existing port 3306 (MySQL default) connections that you may already be actually running on your local machine. If this isn't the case, you can either omit the PORT attribute or keep it explicit, but change it to 3306.

Comment: I am running the Python code from Jupyter Notebook. I use the command prompt to launch Jupyter Notebook online, open the .ipynb file with that code, and run the code from there. It seems like I am trying to get a connection from my local machine and I don't have a static IP to whitelist and based on that, I am attempting to follow step 6. Please let me know given this information, whether or not I am on the right track to resolving the issue.

Comment: @MihirRavishankar yes, if you're running Jupyter Notebook on your local machine, using Cloud SQL Proxy is the direction you want to go.

Comment: I have tried using Cloud SQL Proxy but I am running into some issues. I would like to schedule a call at a time that works for you to explain my issues and get help resolving them. My email address is mihir.ravishankar@gmail.com. Feel free to reach out to me at this email address and we can schedule a call from there.